# python console error: ImportError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django

I am following the django quick install instructions.

- I activated the venv
- I did `pip install django` from inside the venv, *with and without* sudo and receive the same message.

To check the install:

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

> "did you...?"

No. I didn't. I didn't do anything extra. This is a new spawning of a vm (built by vagrant/puppet) that already has virtualenv installed. The only thing I had to do to prep this venv was to make it not use the systems python 2.7.8. `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.4 myvirtualenv`

*(On a separate pyramid-based project, it would fail during setup (`python setup.py development.ini` would fail with `invalid command name 'development.ini'` I don't need that project for this project, but saying this here may reveal something about the install.).*

So how do I make this go away?

Edit: clarified for answers from @catavaran & @Burhan Khalid

Comment: I apologize for the vast edit. I was pretty pissed off about the whole thing (it should Just Work) when i wrote the original.

Comment: What is the output of `pip install django`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `pip install django` gives a permissions error when creating directories in the `Cleaning up...` stage.

Comment: I hope you didn't create the environment with sudo.

Comment: Newp. See my solution below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was permissions earlier in the setup.

It leads to Django being unable to complete it's install. `pip install django` would fail with a `permissions error` on a `mkdir` during the `Cleaning up...` segment of the install. And while all the files may have been installed, I suppose it wasn't completely configged.

`sudo pip install django` is no better because the django install now has su permissions which helps with the mkdir problem above, while potentially creating other problems.

After both installs, the python console `import django` would error.

The fix: the virtual env dirs need to be owned by the user that invoked the virtual envs.

```
sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /opt/myenv
```

In my case, puppet created the venv and dirs as the root user.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect here is where you went wrong:

1. You created a virtual environment (`virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.4`)
2. Next, you forgot to activate it; or you activated it and then you did `sudo pip install django`.

`sudo pip` will run the system wide `pip`, installing django for Python 2.7.8, rather than for the virtual environment.

If you exit the virtual environment and try to import django - it will work.

To fix the problem, make sure you activate the virtual environment and then **do not use sudo to install packages**.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing/using django you should activate your virtualenv.  And do not `sudo` while you call `pip`:

```
$ source ~/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate
$ pip install django
```